# Can the save files from the Steam version of Nier Automata be used in the Microsoft Store version?

Tags: steam, pc, nier-automata, microsoft-store

With the Microsoft Store version of Nier Automata being released, I'm seriously considering getting that version to play after I lost interest in trying to play the Steam version when it stopped detecting my controllers. I was able to get pretty far into the game (midway 3rd playthrough) so I would like it if I could continue progress from there.

Are the saves compatible? Or will I have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to port my Microsoft store version save to steam version using NierAutoModSave v0.1-jimmyazrael : https://github.com/jimmyazrael/NierAutoModSave
I got my save files from "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\39EA002F.NieRAutomataPC_n746a19ndrrjg\SystemAppData\wgs\000901FE32A06AED_0000000000000000000000007B6DEDD6\40CE6D81E3A648E3BC8E849E0BB3A933"
(for the microsoft store Ver). and replace steam saves inside (Documents\My Games\NieR_Automata)
the file with the long name is the slotdata file
and the other one is the gamedata (probably).

I don't know if you can do the vise-versa tho.

Answer (score 1):

:< sadly.. I don't think they can be used directly .. the save file's structure is different between 2 version.
Hope the will be some app to convert between them soon xD. [image]